# Why doesn't my div do margin under navbar when i try to expand it?

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem with my navbar. When I try to expand it by using toggle button (on media max-width), my green div stays in the same place without doing margin under my navbar. I hope somebody will help me with that. I guess the problem is with my static `height` of `nav` and `top:60px;`

```
nav
{
  height:60px;
  background-color:powderblue;
}

    @media (max-width: 554px) {
      .icon
      {
        display:block;
      }
      ul
      {
        flex-direction:column;
        position:fixed;
        top:60px;
        width:100%;
        display:none;
}
}
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/h9s8a4yu/2/

Comment: Which CSS rule isn't being applied?

Comment: @Amith I'm new to css could you tell me what do I wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What should happen to the green div? Where should it go?

Comment: When I click toggle button, there are 5 options. Green div should be under "feedback option"

Comment: OK, i've done it by adding nav.active in css which increases size of this nav. As i thought problem was with height and top parameter.

Comment: I'ts because the float property, or just follow the Nidhi anwser

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your positions and you have to change some CSS for small screens

```css
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:20px;
}
a
{
  color:black;
}

nav
{
  height:60px;
  background-color:powderblue;
}

.logo
{
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  float:left;
  padding-left:30px;
}
ul
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  float:right;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  list-style:none;
  margin-right:30px;
  display:block;
}
li
{
  float:left;
  margin-left:15px;
  padding-top:20px;
}
.fa
{
   float:right;
  margin-right:15px;
  padding-top:20px;
  
  
}
.icon
{
   float:right;
   display:none;
}
ul a:hover
{
  background-color:red;
}

@media (max-width: 554px) {
  nav {
    height: auto;
    }
  .icon
  {
    display:block;
  }
  ul
  {
    flex-direction:column;
    position:relative;
    top:60px;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
    float: none;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.active
  {
    display:block;
  }
  li
  {
    float: none;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    background-color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
  }
  li:hover
  {
    background-color:red;
  }
  .clear {
    clear: both;
  }
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<nav>
  <div class="logo">
  Logo
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 <ul id="expand_list">
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">feedback</a></li>
 </ul>
 
  
</nav>

<div style="margin-top:30px;width:100%;height:300px;background-color:green;">

</div>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  
    const list =document.getElementById("expand_list");
    list.classList.toggle("active");

  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fixed height of `60px` can be problematic. So it's better to make it flexible. And set `30%` and `70%` width to logo and navigation respectively.

```css
nav {
  /* height:60px; */
  background-color:powderblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.logo
{
  color:white;
  font-size:40px;
  float:left;
  padding-left:30px;
  width: 30%;
}
ul
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  float:right;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  list-style:none;
  /* margin-right:30px; */
  width: 70%;
}
.icon
{
   float:right;
   display:none;
   width: 70%;
}
```

If you position an element as `fixed` it will be taken out of natural flow and the green div won't be aware of it. And your active class should toggle display `flex` instead of `block` as you have set `flex` for `ul` above.

```css
@media (max-width: 554px) {
...
  ul
  {
    flex-direction:column;
    /* position:fixed; */
    /* top:60px; */
    width:100%;
    display:none;
  }
  ul.active
  {
    /* display:block; */
    display: flex;
  }
...
}
```